# Check kendo spreadsheet for validation errors

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, kendo-ui, telerik

Using a (ASP.NET Core) [Kendo spreadsheet](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/spreadsheet/configuration/sheets.rows.cells.validation), how to know if on the sheet are or not validation errors and what kind of if any.

I used this code to add validation

```
myCell.Validation(v => v
    .ComparerType("custom")
    .DataType("custom")
    .From("R[0]C[0] > 0")
    .Type("warning")
    .ShowButton(true)
    .AllowNulls(true)
    .TitleTemplate("Alerte de validation")
    .MessageTemplate("Attention, cette valeur est négative !"));
```

Comment: I was intrigued by your question, because I'm going to likely need to do something similar in the future. I dug into it a bit, but couldn't get it to work. It looked like it was possible at some point according to https://www.telerik.com/forums/retrieve-validation-errors-programatically  however, I tried getting that to work with the .NET Core spreadsheet and I'm not seeing a validation valid property  repl: https://netcorerepl.telerik.com/mxECEPFM53D3Q94133

Comment: @G_P please see this one https://www.telerik.com/forums/check-kendo-spreadsheet-for-validation-errors#1618284

Comment: Thanks for the notification. Even though the error doesn't get raised on paste, at least it still flags the cell as being invalid.